# How to stop webkit animation inside inner circle div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have five circle divs nested and I wanna give them pulse animation.I also have a text container which is on the fifth div therefore when I give css animation class to first outer circle it applies for all nested ones and I dont want it to be applied for my text container.

Unfortunately I cant change the position of myText div because when I change it it will be very big problem to relocate it.I cant share exactly the real example of my project because of copyright issues.I should find a solution without changing its position.Is there anyway to do that?

I tried something like below but didnt work as I cant manipulate the animation inside inner circle

```
.myText{ animation-play-state: paused;}
```

```css
#first-circle{border-radius:50%;width:643px;height:643px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:1px solid #000;-webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
#second-circle{position:absolute;border-radius:50%;border:1px solid #000;width:508px;height:508px;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-254px 0 0 -254px}
#third-circle{position:absolute;width:382px;height:382px; border:1px solid #000;border-radius:50%;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-191px 0 0 -191px}
#fourth-circle{position:absolute;width:254px;height:254px;border:1px solid #000;border-radius:50%;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-127px 0 0 -127px}
#fifth-circle{position:absolute;font-size:14px;width:128px;height:128px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;border-radius:50%;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-64px 0 0 -64px}
.myText{
margin-top:55px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

```html
 <div id="first-circle" >      
        <div id="second-circle" >
          <div id="third-circle" >
            <div id="fourth-circle" >
              <div id="fifth-circle" >
                <div class="myText">
                My Text
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So you need only the outer most circle to have pulse animation not for 4 other circles?

Comment: I only want myText div to be paused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it differently using less elements.

```css
.box {
  margin:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:500%;
  padding-top:500%;
  border:2px solid; /* 1 circle here */
  border-radius:50%;
  /* 3 circles here */
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 75%,#000 calc(75% + 1px) calc(75% + 2px),transparent calc(75% + 3px)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 50%,#000 calc(40% + 1px) calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 25%,#000 calc(25% + 1px) calc(25% + 2px),transparent calc(25% + 3px))
    /* to add another circle
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent X%,#000 calc(X% + 1px) calc(X% + 2px),transparent calc(X% + 3px))*/;
  animation:pulsate 1s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
```

In your case you are using nested elements and the scale effect of the outer element will affect all the inner ones and you cannot disable this.